# Getting error about json and i am new in Android World

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I m getting this error when i click a button in Activity
i m developing a Application in Android studio and getting error about json and  i m  not sure how to handle this error

**Error Detail**

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a 
>   null object reference at com.example.tourista.DataParser.getAllnearbyPlaces(DataParser.java:62)
>      at com.example.tourista.DataParser.parse(DataParser.java:100)

```
private List<HashMap<String,String>> getAllnearbyPlaces (JSONArray jsonArray)
{

//Line There i m getting Error

    int counter = jsonArray.length();

    List<HashMap<String,String>> NearbyPlacesList = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String,String> NearbyplaceMap = null;

    if (jsonArray != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            try {
                NearbyplaceMap = getSingleNearbyPlace((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
                NearbyPlacesList.add(NearbyplaceMap);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    return NearbyPlacesList;
}

public List<HashMap<String,String>>  parse(String JSONdata)
{
    JSONArray jsonArray= null;
    JSONObject jsonObject;


    try
    {
        jsonObject =new JSONObject(JSONdata);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return getAllnearbyPlaces(jsonArray);

}
```

Comment: Review comment: take care about formatting when posting a question

Comment: Thanks for Highlighting and  Next time i will take care of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is for this line : `int counter = jsonArray.length();`

if you have a null object you can't call any method of that

your jsonArray is null so you can't call jsonArray.length()

you should put `int counter = jsonArray.length();` bellow `if (jsonArray != null) {`

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case

`jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results")` probably throws a `JSONException` so your array is never initialized and remains `null`. Look in your logs and you will probably see some red lines of text with the error.

To learn more about Nullpointerexceptions read:

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hey Edward van Raak, can you help me answer this other question that I have?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985251/speech-to-text-failed-not-able-to-find-the-problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more code. Who is calling the getAllnearbyPlaces (JSONArray jsonArray)?

When this class is called you are passing a null JSONArray